# phpunit autoload clashes, phpunit autoload get's overriden

Tags: php, phpunit, autoload

My FW uses an autoload function, which I add via `spl_autoload_register('autoload');`
I run phpunit on a directory. After it executes the first test, the system crashes with:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): 
Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php' (include_path='.:/ ......)
in /home/test/functions.php on line 139
```

This points to **my** autolaod function, and not the one phpunit is suppose to use.
Does this mean my function is being used first, and then the phpunit one, and it crashes in my function?

If I change my `autoload` to use `include` instead of `require_once` it will work fine. So I guess this is an order of autoload functions issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `include_once` instead of `require_once` in your autoload function, it will avoid to fatal if the file is not found.

Or you can put your autoloader at the end of the SPL autoloader stack by using

```
spl_autoload_register('autoload', true, true);
```

Giving your bootstrap to phpunit, can probably fix the issue. In your `phpunit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php">
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Seems the bootstrap directive I use in the XML config for PHPunit, puts my `autoload` first. any idea how to run my bootstrap after?

Comment: I know, anyway I solved it by having a specific autoload just for when running tests. I used include_once so it works fine this way.

Comment: The third argument to spl_autoload_register, if true, will prepend it to the autoload stack according to php docs (ie put it at the start, not the end).